# Why's my image fade behaving weirdly when fading into next & last image in the array?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

I don't understand why the previous image's being shown for a split second before moving on to the next image upon clicking.

Also, when I reach the last image, it should redirect to indexTwo.html which it does successfully. However, 'image down' coming from the `alt` attribute in `<img/>` is being shown for like two seconds before it reaches indexTwo.html successfully.

I tried many many different attempts to rectify this, way too many to list!

How can I prevent this behavior from happening?

Here's my html:

```
<img id="the-image" class="img-responsive"
     src="http://tech21info.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/chrome-logo-200x200.png"
     alt="image down"
     onclick="clickedImage()"
/>
```

Here's my js:

```
let theImage = document.getElementById('the-image');

let index = [
    "http://tech21info.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/chrome-logo-200x200.png",
    "https://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/155_drupal/200x200.png",
    "https://townandcountryremovals.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/firefox-logo-200x200.png"
];

let op = 1;
let imageId = 0;

let clickedImage = () => {
    // start animation opacity
    if(op === 1) {
        let timer = setInterval(() => {
            if(op <= 0.1) {
                // load the next image
                imageId = imageId + 1;
                console.log(imageId);
                theImage.src = index[imageId];

                if (imageId >= index.length) {
                    window.location = "indexTwo.html";
                }

                // reset the opacity
                theImage.style.opacity = op = 1;
                clearInterval(timer);
            } else {
                op -= 0.1;
                theImage.style.opacity = op;
            }
        }, 100);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are overflowing the array.

When `imageId == 3` then the following line:

```
theImage.src = index[imageId];
```

results in `theImage.src` being set to `undefined`.

An easy way to resolve this would be to rearrange your code so that the image only advances to the next image if the id is within the bounds of the array.

```
let clickedImage = () => {
    // start animation opacity
    if(op === 1) {
        let timer = setInterval(() => {
            if(op <= 0.1) {
                // load the next image
                imageId = imageId + 1;
                console.log(imageId);

                if (imageId >= index.length) {
                    window.location = "indexTwo.html";
                } else {
                    theImage.src = index[imageId];
                    // reset the opacity
                    theImage.style.opacity = op = 1;

                }
                clearInterval(timer);
            } else {
                op -= 0.1;
                theImage.style.opacity = op;
            }
        }, 100);
    }
};
```